# Select keeps resetting even though model updates

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

Here's the html for a select I'm trying to build.

```
<select
  class="form-control"
  ng-options="country.code as country.name for country in countries track by country.code"
  ng-model="country_code"
  name="country_code">
</select>
```

The select populates, and when I chose an option the model does update. However, the select keeps resetting and I'm not sure why.

Here's a plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/nEKP0xDhrdrIeDPml7Am?p=preview

The reason I need `track by` is that I'm building a form that will be submitted the old-fashioned non-ajax way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you are better of using ng-repeat with `options` element

http://plnkr.co/edit/yYysAHs6Ks5cCY4ZMjyg?p=preview

```
<select
      class="form-control"
      ng-model="country_code"
      name="country_code">
      <option value="{{country.code}}" ng-repeat="country in countries track by country.code">{{country.name}}</option>
</select>
        {{country_code}}
```

Comment: This only works if you drop the `country.id as`. However I need the model to be the code, not the actual country object.

Comment: The model would be whatever you put in `value=""` as in plunker preview, the model is `country_code` and that's what IS displayed with `{{country_code}}` it's not the whole object

Answer (score 1):

Basically the use of **select as** and **track by** together is not possible

From ngOptions docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

> Do not use select as and track by in the same expression. They are not designed to work together.

As already said, use use *country as country.name*.

```
<body ng-app="app">
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
<select
  class="form-control"
  ng-options="country as country.name for country in countries track by country.code"
  ng-model="country_code"
  name="country_code">
    </select>
    {{country_code.code}}
 </body>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/xa3XtyMwfJjqvCKmjCvo?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

[See the Angular documentation on `ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

> Note: ngModel compares by reference, not value. This is important when binding to an array of objects

Instead of `country.code as country.name`, use `country as country.name` so the reference is compared correctly.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Na2tIMDLxVS19jnsU4kE?p=preview

Of course you can no longer use `country_code` directly -- instead you would use `country_code.code` (or rename the model as I have).

Your submitting of a form in a non-ajax way concerns me, though.  I don't see why you would have to do that.